# R: Drawing Circles around a Point in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following data:

```
library(ggplot2)


set.seed(123)

# Simulate 100 points from a Poisson distribution with lambda = 5
data <- rpois(100, 5)

# Estimate lambda using Maximum Likelihood Estimation (MLE)
lambda_mle <- mean(data)

# Define the log-likelihood function
log_likelihood <- function(lambda) {
    sum(dpois(data, lambda, log = TRUE))
}

# Create a sequence of lambda values
lambda_values <- seq(5, 5.5, by = 0.01)

# Calculate the log-likelihood for each lambda value
log_likelihood_values <- sapply(lambda_values, log_likelihood)

# Create a data frame for plotting
df <- data.frame(lambda = lambda_values, log_likelihood = log_likelihood_values)

# Define candidate points
candidates <- data.frame(lambda = c(5.1, 5.2), log_likelihood = sapply(c(5.1, 5.2), log_likelihood))
candidates$candidate <- c("Candidate Solution #1", "Candidate Solution #2")
```

Based on this data, I then made the following plot

```
ggplot(df, aes(lambda, log_likelihood)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point(aes(x = lambda_mle, y = log_likelihood[which.min(abs(lambda_values - lambda_mle))], color = "Estimated Value"), size = 3) +
    geom_point(aes(x = 5, y = log_likelihood[which.min(abs(lambda_values - 5))], color = "True Value"), size = 3) +
    geom_point(data = candidates, aes(x = lambda, y = log_likelihood, color = candidate), size = 3) +
    labs(x = "Lambda", y = "Log-Likelihood", 
         title = "Log-Likelihood Function for Poisson Distribution") +
    theme_minimal() +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("True Value" = "green", "Estimated Value" = "red", "Candidate Solution #1" = "purple", "Candidate Solution #2" = "orange")) +
    geom_text(aes(lambda_mle, log_likelihood[which.min(abs(lambda_values - lambda_mle))], 
                  label = round(lambda_mle, 2), color = "Estimated Value"), hjust = -0.2, vjust = -1.5) +
    geom_text(aes(5, log_likelihood[which.min(abs(lambda_values - 5))], 
                  label = 5, color = "True Value"), hjust = -0.2, vjust = 1.5) +
    geom_text(data = candidates, aes(x = lambda, y = log_likelihood, label = lambda, color = candidate), hjust = 0.5, vjust = -1) +
    xlim(5, 5.5) +
    labs(color = "Legend")
```

[image]

**My Question:** I am trying to draw a purple circle of radius = 0.1 centered around the purple dot, and an orange circle of radius = 0.1 centered around the orange dot:

[image]

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks!

**Note:** The circumference of the circles can be made with dotted lines or non-dotted lines

Comment: You could use ‘geom_point(shape=21, color=“black”, fill=NA, size=5)’ or ‘ggforce::geom_circle’

Comment: @ Jon Spring: Thank you so much for your reply! I will start looking into this (I have never heard of ggforce before). If you have time, could you please show me how to do this? thank you so much!

Comment: @ Jon Spring: Can you please take a look at this related question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77460812/r-shading-shapes-in-ggplot thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP here - I think I figured it out!

```
ggplot(df, aes(lambda, log_likelihood)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point(aes(x = lambda_mle, y = log_likelihood[which.min(abs(lambda_values - lambda_mle))], color = "Estimated Value"), size = 3) +
    geom_point(aes(x = 5, y = log_likelihood[which.min(abs(lambda_values - 5))], color = "True Value"), size = 3) +
    geom_point(data = candidates, aes(x = lambda, y = log_likelihood, color = candidate), size = 3) +
    geom_point(data = candidates[candidates$candidate == "Candidate Solution #1",], aes(x = lambda, y = log_likelihood), size = 100, shape = 1, color = "purple") +
    geom_point(data = candidates[candidates$candidate == "Candidate Solution #2",], aes(x = lambda, y = log_likelihood), size = 100, shape = 1, color = "orange") +
    labs(x = "Lambda", y = "Log-Likelihood", 
         title = "Log-Likelihood Function for Poisson Distribution") +
    theme_minimal() +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("True Value" = "green", "Estimated Value" = "red", "Candidate Solution #1" = "purple", "Candidate Solution #2" = "orange")) +
    geom_text(aes(lambda_mle, log_likelihood[which.min(abs(lambda_values - lambda_mle))], 
                  label = round(lambda_mle, 2), color = "Estimated Value"), hjust = -0.2, vjust = -1.5) +
    geom_text(aes(5, log_likelihood[which.min(abs(lambda_values - 5))], 
                  label = 5, color = "True Value"), hjust = -0.2, vjust = 1.5) +
    geom_text(data = candidates, aes(x = lambda, y = log_likelihood, label = lambda, color = candidate), hjust = 0.5, vjust = -1) +
    xlim(5, 5.5) +
    ylim(-230, -210) + 
    labs(color = "Legend")
```

[image]

**Shaded Colors:**

```
library(scales)

ggplot(df, aes(lambda, log_likelihood)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point(aes(x = lambda_mle, y = log_likelihood[which.min(abs(lambda_values - lambda_mle))], color = "Estimated Value"), size = 3) +
    geom_point(aes(x = 5, y = log_likelihood[which.min(abs(lambda_values - 5))], color = "True Value"), size = 3) +
    geom_point(data = candidates, aes(x = lambda, y = log_likelihood, color = candidate), size = 3) +
    geom_point(data = candidates[candidates$candidate == "Candidate Solution #1",], aes(x = lambda, y = log_likelihood), size = 50, shape = 21, color = "purple", fill = scales::alpha("purple", 0.5) ) +
    geom_point(data = candidates[candidates$candidate == "Candidate Solution #2",], aes(x = lambda, y = log_likelihood), size = 50, shape = 21, color = "orange", fill = scales::alpha("orange", 0.5) ) +
    labs(x = "Lambda", y = "Log-Likelihood", 
         title = "Log-Likelihood Function for Poisson Distribution") +
    theme_minimal() +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("True Value" = "green", "Estimated Value" = "red", "Candidate Solution #1" = "purple", "Candidate Solution #2" = "orange")) +
    geom_text(aes(lambda_mle, log_likelihood[which.min(abs(lambda_values - lambda_mle))], 
                  label = round(lambda_mle, 2), color = "Estimated Value"), hjust = -0.2, vjust = -1.5) +
    geom_text(aes(5, log_likelihood[which.min(abs(lambda_values - 5))], 
                  label = 5, color = "True Value"), hjust = -0.2, vjust = 1.5) +
    geom_text(data = candidates, aes(x = lambda, y = log_likelihood, label = lambda, color = candidate), hjust = 0.5, vjust = -1) +
    xlim(5, 5.5) +
    ylim(-220, -210) 
labs(color = "Legend")
```

[image]